# .htaccess URL Rewrite doesn't see get values

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite my url:

```
http://localhost/api/user/?a=xxx&b=yyy
```

to:

```
http://localhost/?controller=user&a=xxx&b=yyy
```

I wrote

```
RewriteRule ^api/([a-z]*)/\\?(.*)$ ?controller=$1&$2 [L]
```

however it doesn't see my get values in first link. Is it any possibility to do that?

Answer (score 0):

When trying to get data from queries you only have to match the path and add `[QSA]`
In your case:

```
RewriteRule ^api/([a-z]+)$ ./index.php?controller=$1 [QSA, L]
```

Observe, I've added `./index.php`, replace this with the original file you want to execute.